# Why is "never[]" keyword used in this example instead of "any[]"?

Tags: typescript

I stumbled onto this example in ts docs inside the Handbook>Type Manipulation>Conditional Types

```
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return
  ? Return
  : never;
 
type Num = GetReturnType<() => number>;
     
type Num = number
 
type Str = GetReturnType<(x: string) => string>;
     
type Str = string
 
type Bools = GetReturnType<(a: boolean, b: boolean) => boolean[]>;
```

I tried to use any and it also gave me the same results why is `never[]` used here what benefits does it provide here instead of `any[]`?

Comment: I’m guessing it’s because functions are contravariant over their parameters – e.g. if a function takes a `T` as a parameter (`f: (T) => …`), it’s safe to assign it a type that means it’s always called with a value of a more specific type as an argument (`f: (U) => …` where `U extends T`). `never` is a subset of every type (because it’s empty). I don’t know why `any` works, though.

Comment: Is your question about the `never` in "else" half of the conditional type, or the fact that `never[]` is used as the type of the `args` parameter?

Comment: yes it was about never[] being used in args parameter sorry for any misunderstanding